# Implementing restrictions for bash application using PKI

Tags: bash, certificate, pki

We have developed internal bash application and we wanted to put a license like thing. However we really doubt if that can achieved using bash like stuff hence we decided to use PKI stuff for restrictions and wondering if PKI or building internal CA would help?

Can someone give me any use cases how this can be achieved? Like signing the bash using internal CA or provide certificate signed with internal ca and check for the validity of the certificate? if the cert is expired and is not signed by internal CA do not run the application.

Any other ideas please?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

### Is signing a solution?

I'm guessing the problem is copy protection? Checking a signature in a Bash script will not really help there.

Generally, any mechanism, that could be easily removed by the user, will probably not do it.

### Asymmetric encryption

Asymmetric encryption could offer a solution (but I'd really recommend to define the problem more clearly first).

#### Downsides

- The encrypted deliverable has to be created individually for each license (which could mean performance or testability issues).
- A PKI would probably have to be put in place.

#### Draft of possible solution

1. Either at build time or during delivery of the program to the license holder, the system encrypts the payload (the licensed script) with the public key of the license holder.
2. The build or delivery system appends the encrypted payload to the wrapper script.
3. That individualized wrapper script is delivered to the license holder.
4. The license holder starts the wrapper script and supplies their private key.
5. The wrapper script decrypts the payload and executes it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well our use case is to define a kind of license for bash application and provide it to license holder so that it should expire at the end of 1 year min or 3 years. Here expire means he should not be able to run that application after expire period hence was thinking about PKI/Cert based solution

Comment: Yes, I see. The certificate could cover the expiration part. But what are its advantages to, for example, a HTTP request to a license server? And the expiration will not be sufficient, if it cannot be enforced: Unless you obfuscate your license checking code in some clever way, users could easily modify or deactivate it.